# What to do if no tag matches main content of question?

Tags: discussion, tags

Question in question (now deleted): [Creating an announcement bar that can be updated-live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681208/creating-an-announcement-bar-that-can-be-updated-live)

> [image]

The OP tagged this question with [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), which made sense at first based on the code posted. After some research, I determined that the *actual* language being asked about is [NAML](http://naml.nabble.com/), for which there is no tag.

How should something like this be handled? Since there was no tag, I edited the title with a prefix ("NAML - foo bar"). Is this appropriate? I also notice that as I write this, the question was put on hold as "too broad" (and then deleted shortly after). Is that another course of action unless the OP clarifies? **How important is taxonomy?**

Comment: I would have added a short explanation what NAML is so any visitors get an idea what that strange a acronym is.

Comment: @rene Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: Side note: "How to create an announcement bar that can be updated live in NAML" would have been better because then the title would still read like an English sentence. It's regarded as a bad practice to just tack tags onto the beginning or end of a question title.

Comment: @BSMP Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taxonomy is [important](https://stackoverflow.com/tags):

> Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

However, neither you nor the OP has the privilege to [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags). What you could have done in this case, is suggest an edit, and in the edit summary ask the reviewers to create the tag. (Reviewing edits requires 2k reputation, so they would be able to do that.) That wouldn't help if the OP approves the edit, or you encounter a couple of robo-reviewers who just blindly click 'Approve' for each suggested edit, but at least you tried.

Comment: Marked as accepted after much deliberation over which one was _most_ helpful. :) One question, though: is creating a tag for something that has only one post a Good Idea?

Comment: @cyberbit yes - *some* question has to be the first one to use a certain tags. There is even a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) for successful tag creation.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the screenshot (thank you!), the main problem here is that the author failed to mention that they were using NAML. You should have edited the question more to specify this fact; the title wasn't enough.

In particular, the bast thing would have been to change the `HTML:` to `NAML:`, and also link it to the NAML webpage.

(I think it was OK to include the HTML tag, if only to have syntax highlighting.)

I think that the main reason why the mod acted like they did was because it was unclear what the OP was asking (it's not too broad once you know it's about NAML). I think that if you would have `@pinged` them and explained the situation, they would have helped to sort the situation out.

Comment: I didn't do anything, blame someone else, will you.

Comment: If you need prettify in a code block that is not default on any current tag consider `<-- language: lang-html -->` instead of adding a tag to get the same.